# Sorry, but we support MySQL version 5.6.0 or later

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am on an ubuntu machine using LAMP, I am trying to install magento. I have downloaded the magento and completed with the Readiness Check. When I am trying to create database it shows the following error:

> Sorry, but we support MySQL version 5.6.0 or later.

What I did was to create an empty database in phpmyadmin namely magento. In the setup wizard of magento I added the following to add a database:

```
Database Server Host:localhost 
Database Server Host:root //phpmyadmin username
Database Server Password:password //phpmyamdin password
Database Name: magento//database name as enter in phpmyadmin
Table prefix: //empty
```

so, is there any quick way how I can upgrade my MySQL version.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu? Ubuntu 16.04 should come with mysql 5.7. Edit, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762384/install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I am using LinuxMint17.2.

Comment: You said "I am on ubuntu machine using LAMP" - sorry, not all linux distros are "ubuntu". I'm using debian and have mysql 5.6 on board (ubuntu based on debian, linux mint based on ubuntu). Anyway, this is no php or programming question so stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask

Comment: I am sorry my fault, i have a bad habit of keep on changing my OS any ways i got the solution and i have shared below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

Uninstall the current verion of mysql by using the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After this Install the MySQL 5.6 by using the following

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

During this you will be asked for the password enter it and thats it.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. And this answer helped me. Thanks, Sir!

Comment: Hello 2019, This will uninstall the current version of mysql and install 5.6 version see if you really need 5.6 version.